# Implementing sending from N and recieving from N with FreeRtos and RF24 radio module

Tags: esp8266, programming

I'm trying to make my first chip send data through a nrf24 radio pipe and the other listen to it. After the first data is received it should switch to transmit mode and itself transmit new data. The main goal of all of this is to implement the raft protocol with at least 3 chips participating. So the requirements would be to have each chip listening all the time and to have it stop listening at random intervals to send a broadcast message to all other chips. Basically the communication is never between just two chips but always one to many. I've come across tutorials such as http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=421081 but it always comes down to a stable Master vs Slaves state while my situation is more dynamic.
This is my current task. The listener works perfectly until the first received message when it opens a writing pipe. It then does not write and does not go back to listening.

```
void test_Task(void *pvParameters){

    printf("some init\n");
    bool hastoSend = false;


    radio.openReadingPipe(1, address);
    while(1){

        radio.startListening();
        if (radio.available()) {
            radio.read(&rx_data, sizeof(rx_data));

                if (rx_data[1] == 101){
                    printf("Received message: %d\n", rx_data[1]);
                    hastoSend = true;
                    printf("%d\n",rx_data[0]);
                    //int someint = *((int*)pvParameters);

                    // turn on led1
                    write_byte_pcf(led1);
                    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(200));
                    write_byte_pcf(0xff);
                }

        }else{
                if (hastoSend){

                    printf("I need to send a message!\n");
                    printf("sending a message\n");
                    radio.openWritingPipe(address2);
                    radio.stopListening();
                    transmit_nrf24();
                    radio.printDetails();
                    hastoSend = false;
                    radio.openReadingPipe(1, address);

                }
        }


    }

}
```

This is my radio setup:

```
static inline void setup_nrf() {

    uart_set_baud(0, 115200);
    gpio_enable(SCL, GPIO_OUTPUT);
    gpio_enable(CS_NRF, GPIO_OUTPUT);

    // radio configuration
    radio.begin();
    radio.setChannel(channel);
    radio.setAutoAck(false);


}
```

For testing purposes the messages being transmitted come from my other device which is just a manual transmitter. What would solve my problem is a way to completely reset the radio when the first message is received so that the pipes do not bother each other and the device could then be re-initialised as a transmitter.

Cheers!

Comment: what is `chip`?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by simply repeating

```
gpio_enable(SCL, GPIO_OUTPUT);
gpio_enable(CS_NRF, GPIO_OUTPUT);

// radio configuration
radio.begin();
radio.setChannel(channel);
radio.setAutoAck(false);
```

before opening a new writing pipe.